# Create an infinite add function

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I'm just wondering if you guys can think of an implementation of such an infinite `add` function in Swift.

```
let result = add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)() // 15
```

I have the basic solution of it for a two parameters call `let res = add(1)(2)`, but can seem to find a way to handle an infinite numbers.

```
func add(a: Int) -> (Int) -> (Int) {
    return { b in a + b }
}
```

I guess the final `()` is required to indicate somekind of 'stop returning a function but return the result instead'.

Comment: What language?  Lambda calculus springs to mind

Comment: I'm looking for an implementation in Swift if possible.

Comment: If you try to write down the type of the function you want to define, you'll find that it's pretty difficult.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift you can't curry an arbitrary number of parameters, unfortunately. ([Some functional libraries go to great lengths to give you behaviour that's kind of like it - but it's limited at a certain number](https://github.com/typelift/Swiftz/blob/master/Swiftz/Curry.swift))

To sum an infinite list, though, you'll need a function like scan:

```
extension SequenceType {
  func scan<T>(var initial: T, combine: (T, Generator.Element) -> T) -> LazySequence<MapSequence<Self, T>> {
    return lazy(self).map {
      element -> T in
      initial = combine(initial, element)
      return initial
    }
  }
}
```

Which works like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].scan(0, combine: +) // [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

But, since the list you're working with is infinite, if you want to use it without diverging, you'll need a function like take:

```
extension SequenceType {
  func take(var n: Int) -> [Generator.Element] {
    var g = self.generate()
    var ret: [Generator.Element] = []
    while --n >= 0, let next = g.next() { ret.append(next) }
    return ret
  }
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
(1..<100).scan(0, combine: +).take(10) // [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
```

Comment: I just wanted to comment that there's also a great library which does exactly that, but then I saw your username and remembered that you're the guy who wrote it :D

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of would be a variadic solution, if you want it more functional than the previous answer from vadian, perhaps use reduce instead of the loop...

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int ...) -> Int {
    return numbers.reduce(0, combine: +)
}


sumOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // returns 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a function with a varidic parameter?

From the Swift Language Guide, slightly changed

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
  var total: Int = 0
  for number in numbers {
    total += number
  }
  return total
}

sumOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // 15
sumOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) // 55
```

Comment: I knew this was possible, the result is correct, but I am looking for a more "functional" way of doing it :)